# Build Error in developing C and MYSQL application

Tags: mysql, c, netbeans, eclipse-cdt

I am writing some code in C which connects to MYSQL server. I am using Netbeans and new to this. I configured it as directed and installed MYSQL Connector C. I also installed CYGWIN GCC, G++, GDB, MAKE from cygwin site. I created a c project and in the properties-> build-> c compiler->Include directories, set the path of mysql connector (C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C 6.0.2\include). Now i write some code to interect with MYSQL server, on build some error occurs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mysql.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {   


MYSQL *conn;
MYSQL_RES *res;
MYSQL_ROW row;
char *server = "localhost";
char *user = "root";
char *password = "aaaa"; /* set me first */
char *database = "mysql";
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
/* Connect to database */
if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server,
     user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
  exit(1);
}
/* send SQL query */
if (mysql_query(conn, "show tables")) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
  exit(1);
}
res = mysql_use_result(conn);
/* output table name */
printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
  printf("%s \n", row[0]);
/* close connection */
mysql_free_result(res);
mysql_close(conn);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

After build following error occurs:

```
build/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/AEM/My     Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.c:26: undefined reference to `_mysql_init'
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/AEM/My    Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.c:28: undefined reference to     `_mysql_real_connect'
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/AEM/My    Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.c:30: undefined reference to   `_mysql_error'
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/AEM/My    Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.c:34: undefined reference to   `_mysql_query'
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/AEM/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.c:35: undefined reference to `_mysql_error'
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/AEM/My  Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.c:38: undefined reference to `_mysql_use_result'
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/AEM/My   Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.c:41: undefined reference to   `_mysql_fetch_row'
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/AEM/My Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.c:44: undefined reference to `_mysql_free_result'
/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/AEM/My  Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2/main.c:45: undefined reference to `_mysql_close'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/AEM/My   Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/AEM/My   Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_2'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin-Windows/cppapplication_2.exe] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

I googled a lot but could not find anything to solve this issue. Need Help.

Comment: Those are linker errors. Are you linking with the MySQL libraries?

Comment: @ Pileborg: HI, In properties-> build-> linker-> additional library directories, i set the path C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt. but same error continues.

Comment: Okay, you set the path to where the library might be, but did you add the actual library somewhere?

Comment: @ Pileborg: Yes,  In properties-> build-> linker-> libraries, I added mysql.lib, mysqlclient.lib, mysys.lib, but its not working. Please tell me one thing, which path should I set from the following? "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" OR "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib\debug " OR "C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C 6.0.2\lib\debug" OR "C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt". I mean either installation path to mysql c connector or installation path to mysql server. since Both are installed in "C:\Program Files\MySQL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add **-lmysql** to link with the mysql library (valid for gcc). Or, if you use another Compiler, tell the Compiler

- where the Libs are (add the Path)
- to link the Library to the executable. This is something different, then adding the Path.

Comment: @Beyer: HI, In properties-> build-> linker-> additional library directories, i set the path C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector C 6.0.2\lib\opt. but same error continues. I am working on WINDOWS XP machine